# How can i get same result with simple Poisson distribution and the Poisson Distribution Function (CDF)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I am comparing the sum of the results of a simple `Poisson Distribution` with the result of the `Poisson Distribution Function (CDF)`. I thought the results were almost similar more or less. I'm using Python, but the question is clear enough regardless of using a programming language.

I want to calculate the probability having `k` equal to 4 or more and i'm testing the two ways. How can I get the same result with both the simple Poisson distribution and the Poisson Distribution Function (CDF)? If it is possible, I would like to place a limit of 10 on the Poisson Distribution Function (CDF), i.e. from 4 to 10

So with the simple Poisson Distribution, add from 4 to 10 (therefore imposing the maximum limit of 10):

```
from scipy.stats import poisson
four = poisson.pmf(4, 1.6)
five = poisson.pmf(5, 1.6)
six = poisson.pmf(6, 1.6)
seven = poisson.pmf(7, 1.6)
eight = poisson.pmf(8, 1.6)
nine = poisson.pmf(9, 1.6)
ten = poisson.pmf(10, 1.6)
a = four + five + six + seven + eight + nine + ten
print(a) 
#result is 0.078
```

While with the Poisson Distribution Function (CDF), I write:

```
b = 1-poisson.cdf(k=4, mu=1.6)
print(b)
#result is 0.023
```

I understand that with the simple Poisson distribution I set the limit to 10, while with the Poisson Distribution Function (CDF) there is no limit, but still the results seem too different from each other. How can I get the same result with both the simple Poisson distribution and the Poisson Distribution Function (CDF)?

The result is `0.078` with the simple Poisson Distribution, while with the Poisson Distribution Function (CDF) it is `0.023`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you calculate $P(X\geq 4)\approx P(X=4)+P(X=5)+P(X=6)+\ldots+P(X=10)= 0.078 $

Cut off at $10$ and rounded to 2 decimal places. In the second case you calculate

$$1-P(X\leq 4)=P(X=5)+P(X=6)+\ldots= 0.023$$

Rounded to 2 decimal places.

You see that you have the extra $P(X=4)$ in the first case. In the case of discrete random variables we have the relation $P(X\geq x)=1-P(X\leq x-1)$. That means to get almost the same result like in the first case you have to calculate $1-P(X\leq 3)=0.079$ (rounded to 2 decimal places). As you have already mentioned, the discrepancy of $0.001$ comes from the cut off at $X=10$ in the first case.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer, sorry. I'm not very good at math. Basically I would like to calculate the probability of 4 or more goals. Initially I only used the simple Poisson Distribution with the limit up to 10. I didn't know about the Poisson Distribution Function (CDF). I read it casually on the web and now I'm trying to delve deeper into it. QUESTION: The logic of the Poisson Distribution Function (CDF) is the same as in my first case, but the difference is that there is no upper limit? So it's >= 4 to infinity?

Comment: @Horiatiki In the second case you have calculated $1-P(X\leq 4)$, which is $P(X\geq 5)$. But in the first case you wanted to calculate $P(X\geq 4)$. The missing terms in the first case (X=5,6,...) does not affect the result not much, only by 0,001.

Comment: So if I want to calculate >= 4, does it mean that the first case is correct, while the second case is wrong?

Comment: If yoo want to calculate $P(X\geq 4)$ you have to calculate $1-P(X\leq 3)$. So the code changes to   'b = 1-poisson.cdf(k=3, mu=1.6) '

Comment: Great, thank you. In this way I obtain 0.07881348722971893, while with simple Poisson of the first case (From 4 to 10) I obtain 0.07881246232022453. Almost identical values. Good :) At this point a question arises: if in the first case I set the limit from 4 to 10, instead in the second case with 1-poisson.cdf(k=3, mu=1.6) what is the maximum limit? 100?

Comment: I think you can use infinity like at wollfram alpha, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum_%28x%3D4%29%5E%28infinity%29+e%5E%28-1.6%29*1.6%5Ex%2Fx%21). You should then a sigma sign, $\sum$.

Comment: Ok, fine, thank you very much. You were very kind and you cleared up a big doubt for me. I vote and accept your answer :)

Comment: You are welcome. It pleases me that is all clear now. Thanks for voting.